# How do I get draw count in pixi.js

Tags: pixi.js

I'm using this code to add a ticker. The draw method looks like this:

```
this.ticker = this.ticker || this.app.ticker.add(this.draw)
```

Here app is the PIXI.Application. The draw method looks like so:

```
private draw(): void {
  console.log(this.ticker.FPS)
}
```

This gives me the FPS but how do I get the draw calls count?

Draw calls are discussed here https://pixijs.io/pixi-batch-renderer/PIXI.brend.BatchRenderer.html

> This object renderer renders multiple display-objects in batches. It can greatly reduce the number of draw calls issued per frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let drawCount = 0;

const renderer = app.renderer as any;
const drawElements = renderer.gl.drawElements;
renderer.gl.drawElements = (...args: any[]) => {
  drawElements.call(renderer.gl, ...args);
  drawCount++;
}; // rewrite drawElements to count draws

app.ticker.add((deltaTime) => {
  console.log(`drawCount: ${drawCount}`);
  drawCount = 0; // clear count per frame
});
```